# How to use str.join()?

Tags: python, string, methods, string-conversion

```
>>>seq = ("a", "b", "c") # This is sequence of strings.
str.join( "-",seq )
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

What went wrong here? I tried to change `"` by `'` but it doesn't help...

```
>>> seq = ("a", "b", "c") 
my_string = "-"
str.join(my_string, seq)
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

why?????

Comment: Are you entering this in the interactive interpreter?  It looks like somehow the line break between your two lines of code isn't being seen.

Comment: As Aaron Hall's answer explains, when you do `str="-"` what you're doing is overwriting the Python default `str()`, which breaks everything ever. It's the same reason you're STRONGLY recommended never to do `list = []` or `dict = []` and etc etc.

Comment: how to fix this? how it suppose to be written?

Comment: @user7777777 there are several good answers, but succinctly, `"-".join(seq)`. The format is `separator.join(sequence)`

Comment: @user7777777 Also, the reason for your `SyntaxError` is unrelated to you trying to do `str=` or even `str.join`. You can't paste multiple lines at once into an interactive interpreter like IDLE. One line at a time :). The interpreter sees more than one line at once, and threw the `SyntaxError` at you to tell you to slow down.

Comment: @  adsmith can you show how to fix this?

Comment: This may be a dumb question. After you type `seq = ("a", "b", "c") `, are you pressing enter before typing `str.join( "-",seq )`?

Comment: Try this, see answer for explanation, and don't do this in Python modules!: `seq = ("a", "b", "c"); my_string = '-'; my_string.join(seq)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done even easier, as the object on which is method called is passed as the first argument, so writing

```
seq = ("a", "b", "c") 
my_string = '-'
print my_string.join(seq)
```

gives

```
'a-b-c'
```

as expected

Answer (score 8):

The problem in your SPECIFIC instance appears to be that you're pasting multiple lines into an interactive interpreter and trying to get them all to parse at once. IDLE (et. al) doesn't like that very much. Do them separately, as in your first example:

```
>>> seq = ("a","b","c")
>>> str.join("-", seq)
# "a-b-c"
```

When you did `str = "-"`, `str.join(seq)` would still work because it's equivalent to `my_string.join(seq)` as noted above, but using the "long-version" (`str.join(separator, sequence)`) doesn't work.

If you want to paste a longer line in a Python shell, it's customary to separate by `;`, but please don't stick these sorts of lines in Python files. I frequently do this to give people reproducible results via email:

```
seq = ("a", "b", "c"); my_string = '-'; my_string.join(seq)
```

An earlier issue was overwriting the `str` constructor. Start a new shell and try this:

```
seq = ("a", "b", "c") 
my_string = '-'
str.join(my_string, seq)
```

you should get this:

```
'a-b-c'
```

It is more common to use join as an instance method:

```
my_string.join(seq)
```

Comment: Yes, but that won't raise `SyntaxError`.

Comment: (This also isn't the case in the *first* posted code .. but it is indeed a problem that arises occasionally.)

Comment: Entering ```del str``` will also bring back the builtin

Comment: @user2864740 my guess is that the OP did `str="-"` in the first code as well. the `>>>` in front of `seq=...` implies it was in an interpreter, and they could have easily done that earlier and simply forgotten.

Comment: @adsmith It still shouldn't be a SyntaxError though.. `seq = ("a", "b", "c"); str='-'; str.join( "-",(seq ))` results in "*TypeError*: join() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: actually, it can be written easier: `my_string.join(seq)`

Comment: @user2864740 You're looking into it too hard -- the `SyntaxError` is because he's copied multiple lines of code into his interpreter at once

Comment: That is more commonly seen, and I've added it.

Comment: @AaronHall I *concur* that such may be the case, which is why I don't agree with this answer as solving the *reported* issue.

Comment: @user2864740 I would wager that the question is asking `How to use str.join()` which is exactly what the answer addresses. The error shown in the question is not caused by not knowing how to use `str.join`, it's caused by not knowing how to use an interpreter. A separate and equally deserving question, but not the one asked or intended by the asker.

Comment: @AaronHall I proposed an edit that explains more-fully what happened with the `SyntaxError`

Comment: I'll make another suggestion for the asker as well.

Comment: I moved that part to the top, and @adsmith's contribution will be rewarded via karma.

Answer (score 1):

`join` is a method of the str data type so you can do...

```
>>> seq = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> "-".join(seq)
'a-b-c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have: `seq = ("a","b","c")`

You can your one of these to syntax (They are actually identical, the latter is more canonical):

```
>>> str.join("-",seq)
'a-b-c'

>>> "-".join(seq)
'a-b-c'
```